# EJB TimerService interval timer with end date

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, ejb

I want to create an EJB Timer running with specific interval, but it also should stop being triggered at some point. EJB's [TimerService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html) seems to offer only 2 possibilities:

- You create infinitely recurring timer with specific interval.
- You create a calendar timer, which has start and end dates, and also allows to events to repeat every N seconds/minutes/hours. The problem is that this repetition does not "roll over", as the documentation clearly states. So if I create a timer to schedule every 5 hours, it'll be every 5 hours *within the day*, and that's not what I want.

The precision I need is hours, so any solution allowing hourly repetition which "rolls over" days is fine.

Thank you.

Comment: it is not clear what is the execution schedule that you need implement. Please clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [ScheduleExpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ScheduleExpression.html) as:

```
ScheduleExpression schedule = new ScheduleExpression();
schedule.start(startDate);
schedule.hour("*/2");
schedule.end(endDate);
Timer timer = timerService.createCalendarTimer(schedule);
```

The above code trigers the Timer every 2 hours for example.

Comment: As I said, this does not roll over days. It treats every day independently, and that's not what I want. For example, if you put 5 hours here, it will run at 00, 05, 10, 15, 20 every day. But I need that the next day it'll run at 01, 06, 11, etc.

Comment: I am not an expert in Timeouts but I am not sure if what you want can be done because the intervals are not even/symetrical as you describe it. You should probably set an independent Timer each day.

Answer (score 0):

This method **getTimers()** gives you the lists of timers are currently active for the bean TimerService. For each timers from the list, perform **getInfo()** to get the timer's info. If this is *null*, then its the scheduler that you have started. Just perform the **cancel()** then, and it will stop your scheduler.

```
List<Timer> timerList = timerService.getTimers();
for(Timer t : timerList){
    if(t.getInfo() ==  null){
        t.cancel();
    }
}
```

So decide from where you want to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 or more timers with same functionality. Or create single time timer, during execution calculate next execution date/time and create next single time timer